# Hello World Phonegap App has wrong resolution on iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I've spent a while trying to sort this and found an unanswered question which I have since lost. But heres the beat:

I used `phonegap create . my.app.id` and it created a hello world boiler plate that looks awful on iphone 6. There are black bars reducing it to an iPhone 4 size and the resolution is wrong.

Symptoms are black bars above and below your app, the status bar and keyboard in the wrong resolution and app being blurry af.

Comment: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: The Documentation has issues, but your issue is mundane. So you can continue to struggle with a trivial issue or read. Your choice. You can also try the real forums - instead. Best of Luck.

Comment: With Cordova/Phonegap your need to do a **lot** of reading. Read the section on Preferences.

Comment: Okay. They recently reorganized. This is [the section](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html) you need to read. Again see *preference*.

Comment: I'm trying to be nice, but you are trying my patience. You have several misunderstadings about Cordova/Phonegap work. Your question is incorrect. Your assumption about resolution and how it controls the screen is incorrect. The first link I gave you is you can move in the right direction. However, it appears you are pig-headed. Read some more of that link and you will find you answer - eventually. I'm not here to give you answer. If don't want to read, you won't go very far with this. Best of Luck.

Comment: You will talking to yourself from now on.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is specify more splash screen sizes. That is what controls the resolution on different devices... I know, don't ask.

For android you need the following:

```
    <splash src="..." density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="..." density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="..." density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="..." density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="..." density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="..." density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="..." density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="..." density="port-xhdpi"/>
```

For iOS you need the following:

```
<splash src="..." width="320" height="480"/>
<splash src="..." width="640" height="960"/>
<splash src="..." width="768" height="1024"/>
<splash src="..." width="1536" height="2048"/>
<splash src="..." width="1024" height="768"/>
<splash src="..." width="2048" height="1536"/>
<splash src="..." width="640" height="1136"/>
<splash src="..." width="750" height="1334"/>
<splash src="..." width="1242" height="2208"/>
<splash src="..." width="2208" height="1242"/>
```

If it's still not displaying correctly check if there isn't another set that is missing from this list.